# How to export (send) image from website to Instagram?

Tags: media

I'm working on a social network website based on Drupal7, This social network is based on photos and users may upload photos and they are accessible in their profile. I need to equip the site to contact to the *Instagram* profile of users and they can send images from my website to their profile in Instagram. I checked the [Instagram Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_block) and [Instagram Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_feeds) and [Drupalgram](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupagram) modules, but from I understand these modules only import images from Instagram, non of them export images to Instgram. How do I can send Images from my website to Instagram?

Comment: last time I looked into this, Instagram didn't allow uploading through their API by design

Comment: Thanks @Geoff , How about twitter and Facebook?

Comment: you can easily add a 'post to' for twitter and facebook (there are modules for that), but I don't know about automatically adding content - you would need to look at their individual API documention to be sure

Comment: Isn't Instagram for pictures only...?

Comment: All my blog have pictures. So I would like post the picture to instagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use module [InstaPost](https://www.drupal.org/project/instapost) for posting nodes to Instagram. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module allows users to post nodes automatically to the online
>   mobile photo-sharing, video-sharing, and social networking service
>   Instagram.

<sup>Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of this module.</sup>

Comment: Nice! Please note the minor improvement (I think) I did to your answer, if you don't like it at all, just perform a rollback.

Answer (score 1):

The [Instagram Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_block) and [Instagram Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/instagram_feeds) and [Drupagram](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupagram) modules work with Instagram.

> ***Instagram block***  integrates with Instagram and creates a block containing your most recent instagram posts.
>
> ***Instagram Feeds***: This is a Feature module. It allows you to create Instagram feeds for your site that will download images from Instagram using filtering by hashtags and / or usernames.
>
> ***Drupagram*** In this early implementation the module will interact with the Instagr.am API and be able to fetch media items. Advanced methods like relationships between Instagr.am users and such will be added later on.

But about posting to Instagram

## Instagram didn't allow uploading through their API by design

Comment: Please make sure you vote to close duplicates - don't answer them and put a note in the answer, that's why we have these systems in place. Just answer the original in future, many thanks

Comment: @Clive In this system you can't vote a question to be duplicate of another question when it has no accepted answer.

Comment: My apologies, that's new (I actually just got stung by exactly the same thing myself on Stack Overflow). You did the right thing by answering the new question!

Comment: Not important. We are all trying to be a useful member of Drupal Stackexchange society ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default you cant upload your image to instagram  but I suggest you using [if this then that](https://ifttt.com/) service,it is awesome, and using `Email to instagram` feature, then in your drupal you can send your blog image automatically  after node create to specified email then it posted to you istagram automatically.

helper links :
[link1](https://ifttt.com/connect/instagram/email)
[link2](https://ifttt.com/recipes/148896-send-instagram-photo-via-gmail-to-email-address-of-your-choice)